# Вывод версии коммита на экран при запуске приложения

Tags: c++, cmake

Система сборки cmake, windows, qtcreator, язык с++
Нагуглил пример, содержимое CMakeLists:

```
execute_process(
COMMAND git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_BRANCH
OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
     )
execute_process(
COMMAND git log -1 --format=%h
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_HASH
OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
        )

add_definitions("-DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}")
add_definitions("-DGIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH}")
```

Далее пытаюсь вывести переменную препроцессора на экран в приложении:

```
#ifdef GIT_COMMIT_HASH
    std::cout << "Commit: " << GIT_COMMIT_HASH << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
#endif
```

Получаю ошибку: main.cpp:15: ошибка: expected expression.

Дело скорее даже в неумении вывести переменную препроцессора на экран, буду рад помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть не хватает кавычек в макросе. Попробуйте

```
add_definitions("-DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\"")
add_definitions("-DGIT_BRANCH=\"${GIT_BRANCH}\"")
```

Comment: Это решило ошибку, спасибо. Но выдает пустую строку, команды из директории попробовал вызвать, все нормально ветку и коммит выдает, а в переменную получается не наполняет.

Comment: @Nixmist Тогда не знаю, в чем дело. Cmake почти не пользовался.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том, что git не был прописан в системных PATH.
Соответственно решением будет либо его вписать туда, либо при нежелании сделать как я:

```
find_package(Git)
if(Git_FOUND)
message("Git found: ${GIT_EXECUTABLE}")
execute_process(
     COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse HEAD
     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_BRANCH
     OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
execute_process(
     COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} log -1 --format=%h
     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_HASH
     OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH="${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}")
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -DGIT_BRANCH="${GIT_BRANCH}")
endif()
```

Вывод информации на экран в main:

```
#ifdef GIT_BRANCH
    std::cout << "Branch: " << GIT_BRANCH << std::endl;
#endif
#ifdef GIT_COMMIT_HASH
    std::cout << "Commit: " << GIT_COMMIT_HASH << std::endl;
#endif
```